# Git pathspec error when using git-archive

Tags: git, branch, archive

I have two branches `Master` and `Newsletterdesign`, and I need the differences from `Newsletterdesign`, but I have a problem with git archive:

```
$ git archive -o Name.zip 5a5e099 $(git diff --name-only 5a5e099^..5a5e099)

Error: fatal: pathspec '-' did not match any files
```

Any idea? Thank you.

Comment: Can you try and put a '`--`' after the first `5a5e099` ? `git archive -o Name.zip 5a5e099 -- $(git diff --name-only 5a5e099^..5a5e099)`

Comment: Hey, thanks, but didn't work :(  throws the same error

Comment: I had forgotten about that question! What is the exact output of `git diff --name-only 5a5e099^..5a5e099`?

Answer (score 0):

The command you tried should work. It's correct. And the reason of the error you are getting will be because of some extra files which is not added into git. Please check for `Untracked files` with the help of `git status`. If you have any untracked files, you may add it to git or remove it or otherwise you can stash it (`git stash`)

I tried your command, it works fine.
`git archive -o update.zip HEAD $(git diff --name-only 70a1ab8^..f62c8eb)`

Answer (score 0):

`git diff #commit1 #commit2` takes all changes between commits and then you pass these changed references to archive command. If there was some file(s) removal from git index database between archived commits,- you will get this error, because naturally you can't include non-existing files into zip. So when scanning for git changes you need to ignore removed files. Do this by appending option  `--diff-filter=d` to *git diff* command. The whole (good) command will look like :

```
git archive -o name.zip HEAD $(git diff --name-only --diff-filter=d #ID_A #ID_B)
```

HTH!